# Returning errorlevels with xcopy from multiple directories

Tags: batch-file, error-handling, xcopy, errorlevel

I'm working on a batch script that will move files from user directories on a VM and generate a log file of the files that were moved.

Here's a graphic of the directory structure.

[image: structure]

This script copies files from the appropriate directories and generates the log file:

```
set hh=%time:~-11,2%
set /a hh=%hh%+100
set hh=%hh:~1%
set dateseed=%date:~10,4%_%date:~4,2%_%date:~7,2%_%hh%%time:~3,2%
set output="C:\Users\Public\Documents\Scanned_%dateseed%.txt"
echo(

>>"%output%" (
    echo(Scanned By: %username%
    echo(Date Scanned: %mydate%
    echo(Time Scanned: %mytime%
    echo(
)

:: echoes the Username, File Name, Size(in KB), Last Modified date, and total number of files in the log file
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
set "current="
set/a counter=0

>>"%output%" (
  for /f "delims=" %%F in (
    'dir /b /s \\SERVER\Path\Users ^| findstr ToBeMoved\'
  ) do (
    for /f "delims=\; tokens=3,4,5*" %%a in ("%%F") do (
      if "!current!" neq "%%b" (
         set "current=%%b"
         if defined footer echo(Total Files Moved: !counter! & echo(
         set/a counter=0, footer=1
         echo(
         echo(%%b
      )
      set/a counter+=1, size=%%~zF, kbSize=size/1024
      echo %%d -- Size: !kbSize! KB -- Last Modified: %%~tF
    )
  )
  if defined footer echo(Total Files Moved: !counter! & echo(
) 
EndLocal

dir /b /s /a:d "\\SERVER\Path\Users\*ToBeMoved" | for /f "delims=\; tokens=3,4,5*" %%a in ('findstr ToBeMoved') do @xcopy /i /s /y "\\SERVER\Path\%%a\%%b\%%c" "E:\Path\%%b\"
```

**Okay, here's my question.**

I often run this script when there are no files in any user's "ToBeMoved" directory. This results in an empty, useless log file that clutters up the directory I keep them in. I know that xcopy has an errorlevel for when it tries to copy from a directory but doesn't find any files.

```
Exit
code  Description
====  ===========
  0   Files were copied without error.
  1   No files were found to copy.
  2   The user pressed CTRL+C to terminate xcopy.
  4   Initialization error occurred. There is not
      enough memory or disk space, or you entered
      an invalid drive name or invalid syntax on
      the command line.
  5   Disk write error occurred.
```

So I was hoping I could use an if statement for my script to do something like this: `if errorlevel 1 (del %output%)`

But I added a segment after the `@xcopy` line of the script that looked like this:

```
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo SUCCESS!
) else (
    echo FAILURE!
)
```

And it always returned `FALURE!`. Is what I'm trying to do possible?

**EDIT:** It might also be worth noting that the output of the line that copies the files from the multiple "ToBeMoved" directories returns a line for every single directory so if there are no files you'll see something like:

```
0 File(s) copied
0 File(s) copied
0 File(s) copied
0 File(s) copied
0 File(s) copied
```

**2nd EDIT:** I changed the if/else statement above to be `if not errorlevel 2` due to advice in the comments. However, the result is always a "SUCCESS!" regardless whether files are copied or not. Any idea why this might be? Is there anyway I could write a for loop to count the number of files in the entire directory tree and save that to a variable to check against?

**3rd EDIT:** I created a test scenario. I made 2 folders on my desktop named "TEST1" and "TEST2". Inside both had 3 folders, "SUB1", "SUB2", and "SUB3". In TEST1\SUB1 I created an empty text file called File1.txt. In TEST2\SUB3 I created another empty text file called File2.txt. I wrote a test batch script:

```
@echo off
xcopy /s/i/y %userprofile%\Desktop\TEST1\SUB1 %userprofile%\Desktop\TEST2\SUB3
echo Error Level = %errorlevel%
xcopy /s/i/y %userprofile%\Desktop\TEST1\SUB2 %userprofile%\Desktop\TEST2\SUB2
echo Error Level = %errorlevel%
xcopy /s/i/y %userprofile%\Desktop\TEST1\SUB3 %userprofile%\Desktop\TEST2\SUB1
echo Error Level = %errorlevel%
xcopy /s/i/y %userprofile%\Desktop\TEST2\SUB1 %userprofile%\Desktop\TEST1\SUB3
echo Error Level = %errorlevel%
xcopy /s/i/y %userprofile%\Desktop\TEST2\SUB2 %userprofile%\Desktop\TEST1\SUB2
echo Error Level = %errorlevel%
xcopy /s/i/y %userprofile%\Desktop\TEST2\SUB3 %userprofile%\Desktop\TEST1\SUB1
echo Error Level = %errorlevel%
pause
```

The result was:

```
C:\Users\username\Desktop\TEST1\SUB1\File1.txt
C:\Users\username\Desktop\TEST1\SUB1\File2.txt
2 File(s) copied
Error Level = 0
0 File(s) copied
Error Level = 0
0 File(s) copied
Error Level = 0
0 File(s) copied
Error Level = 0
0 File(s) copied
Error Level = 0
C:\Users\username\Desktop\TEST2\SUB3\File1.txt
C:\Users\username\Desktop\TEST2\SUB3\File2.txt
2 File(s) copied
Error Level = 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Change `if errorlevel 1` into `if not errorlevel 2`. `if errorlevel n` is true for any value equal or greater than `n`

Comment: So.. if errorlevel is 1 then its also true for errorlevel is 0?

Comment: Yes.  If errorlevel is 5, then any check for a value equal or lower to 5 will be true. When you test using `if errorlevel ` syntax, you check from higher to lower values.

Comment: @MCND See my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

**edited** Original response at the end.

I should be missing something obvious, but, I've been unable to get the `xcopy.exe` (Windows 10 64bit, spanish locale) to generate a `errorlevel 1` exit code, documented or not.

So, I have started the debugger and, after some tests, this is what I have seen:

- `xcopy` internally uses a method called `DisplayMessageAndExit` to, well, display a message and exit. It also uses several `exit` calls to leave the program on some events (ex. <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>)
- None of the `exit` calls uses a value of `1`
- From the list of calls made to `DisplayMessageAndExit`, none of them use a value of `1` as exit code
- From the list of calls made to `DisplayMessageAndExit` only one of them use the MessageID `0x5622` (in my install the resources associated are in `C:\Windows\System32\es-ES\ulib.dll.mui`, it is locale dependent), that is `No se encuentra el archivo: %1` (`File not found - %1`), and the exit code used in the call is `4`

Maybe there is a way in which `xcopy` is able to generate the `1` exit code, but I don't know how. So, I don't see a way to handle the case of non files copied using the `xcopy` exit code (that makes the original answer unusable in this case).

***note***: to any reader, if you know what I am not seeing, please, comment.

The simplest way to deal with it is to first check if there is anything to copy. The `/L` switch of the `xcopy` command will list the files without copying them

```dos
for /f "tokens=3,4,* delims=\;" %%a in ('
    dir /b /s /ad "\\SERVER\Path\Users\*ToBeMoved"
') do (

    xcopy /i /s /y /l "\\SERVER\Path\%%a\%%b\%%c" "E:\Path\%%b\" | findstr /b /l /c:"0 File(s) copied" > nul
    if not errorlevel 1 (
        echo No files found
    ) else (
        xcopy /i /s /y "\\SERVER\Path\%%a\%%b\%%c" "E:\Path\%%b\" 
        if errorlevel 2 (
            echo Problems in the copy
        ) else (
            echo SUCESS
        )
    )

)
```

---

Original answer

```dos
for /f "tokens=3,4,* delims=\;" %%a in ('
    dir /b /s /ad "\\SERVER\Path\Users\*ToBeMoved"
') do (
    xcopy /i /s /y "\\SERVER\Path\%%a\%%b\%%c" "E:\Path\%%b\" 
    if errorlevel 2 (
        echo Problems in the copy
    ) else if errorlevel 1 (
        echo No files found
    ) else (
        echo SUCESS
    )
)
```

Comment: When I make sure there are no files to be copied, I see this:

0 File(s) copied
SUCCESS
0 File(s) copied
SUCCESS

Comment: @MCNC I added another edit where I tried to debug my issue.

Comment: Any way I could use this: `>nul 2>nul dir /a-d /s "folderName\*" && (echo Files exist) || (echo No files found)` to only check for files in the "ToBeMoved" sub-directories?

Comment: @Neal, Answer updated, but you will not like it (at least, I don't like it)

Comment: @Neal, Yes, I was writing and I didn't see your comment.